# What application can I use for cropping quickly (selecting multiple areas of an image)?

Tags: software-recommendation, image-processing, image-editor

I have scanned some family albums on my flatbed scanner. The scanner glass has room for three photos, so I ended up with nearly 500 `JPEG`s that needs to be cropped to three images each.

[GIMP](http://www.gimp.org/) seems to be a little slow for this kind of job. Is there any other photo editing tool that would easily let me draw three rectangles, and crop them, and save each selection in a different file?

Comment: What *I* would do is quickly write a PHP script that did this (using the GD graphics library), but I don't know if that's an option in this case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like you may find a solution on the Ubuntu forums here; http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1429439 download the python script install the pre requisites,

```
sudo apt-get install python-tk python-imaging python-imaging-tk
```

run the application, load file, select areas to crop with mouse and click go, pictures of the areas will be saved to file in the folder with the photo. see below:

[image]

View of files in nautilus

[image]

Comment: +1, +100 if I could. This rocks. And it's only 240 lines in Python!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at gThumb it has good basic editing capabilities including cropping. I use gThumb for my default viewer.